# Convert column data to array for further processing

Tags: php, bash, shell, awk

What is the easiest way to covert a column from a csv file to an array format?

I'd have 3 columns like la_liga, playernames_laliga,, and teamid_laliga. Basically, I'd want anything close to the array format, is there a way to do this using command line? There are way too many rows to do this manually so I do need the basic array format that I can directly use for further manipulation.

```
Athletic Bilbao 336 The Parmtree
Atletico Madrid 798466  Santiagounreal
Barcelona   90402   TW
Celta Vigo  24214   Bonz
Deportivo La Coruna 142758  Boom Shakalaka
Espanyol    1658    Tangtastic
Getafe  8333    Declan McCarthy
Granada 2253    Green Windmill
Levante 14069   In Tommy We Trust
Malaga  4877    Ajay
Mallorca    77201   Emperikal
Osasuna 2714    Declan Quinn
Rayo Vallecano  171 Hillbilly Pete
Real Betis  32696   Billy Gilmore
Real Madrid 4   Demi
Real Sociedad   485 Yossi
Real Zaragoza   227 Scroobius Mac
Sevilla 8157    Chris_White
Valencia    4835    Old School
Valladolid  69246   Pepin
```

which in CSV

```
"Athletic Bilbao","336","The Parmtree"
"Atletico Madrid","798466","Santiagounreal"
"Barcelona","90402","TW"
"Celta Vigo","24214","Bonz"
"Deportivo La Coruna","142758","Boom Shakalaka"
"Espanyol","1658","Tangtastic"
"Getafe","8333","Declan McCarthy"
"Granada","2253","Green Windmill"
"Levante","14069","In Tommy We Trust"
"Malaga","4877","Ajay"
"Mallorca","77201","Emperikal"
"Osasuna","2714","Declan Quinn"
"Rayo Vallecano","171","Hillbilly Pete"
"Real Betis","32696","Billy Gilmore"
"Real Madrid","4","Demi"
"Real Sociedad","485","Yossi"
"Real Zaragoza","227","Scroobius Mac"
"Sevilla","8157","Chris_White"
"Valencia","4835","Old School"
"Valladolid","69246","Pepin"
```

Desired Output:

```
$col1=array("Athletic Bilbao","Atletico Madrid","Barcelona","Celta Vigo","Deportivo La Coruna","Espanyol","Getafe","Granada","Levante","Malaga","Mallorca","Osasuna","Rayo Vallecano","Real Betis","Real Madrid","Real Sociedad","Real Zaragoza","Sevilla","Valencia","Valladolid");
$col2=array('336','798466','90402','24214','142758','1658','8333','2253','14069','4877','77201','2714','171','32696','4','485','227','8157','4835','69246');
$col3=array("The Parmtree","Santiagounreal","TW","Bonz","Boom Shakalaka","Tangtastic","Declan McCarthy","Green Windmill","In Tommy We Trust","Ajay","Emperikal","Declan Quinn","Hillbilly Pete","Billy Gilmore", "Demi","Yossi","Scroobius Mac","Chris_White","Old School","Pepin");
```

Someone must have a ready-made script for this, right?

Comment: Can you provide *both* example input and desired output?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth  I've given a sample input and output with an intermediary step

Comment: If you want to output valid PHP array syntax, parse if with PHP and look at [var_export](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). But can you give more details as to why you think you need to do this? There is probably a better solution.

Comment: @cbuckley Doesn't have to be valid PHP array syntax...I I can get the basic array format, that should be enough. If I can get something like this - "Athletic Bilbao","Atletico Madrid","Barcelona","Celta Vigo".... as the output, that is enough. I don't mind writing a little on the side. I do need this data to perform database operations, validations etc...It's for a personal site, a open-source game, that we have, and we quickly wanna get new registrations in (which was sadly done through google docs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=col[i] (NR==1?"":FS) $i} END{gsub(/"/,"\047",col[2]); for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "$col%d=array(%s);\n",i,col[i]}' file
$col1=array("Athletic Bilbao","Atletico Madrid","Barcelona","Celta Vigo","Deportivo La Coruna","Espanyol","Getafe","Granada","Levante","Malaga","Mallorca","Osasuna","Rayo Vallecano","Real Betis","Real Madrid","Real Sociedad","Real Zaragoza","Sevilla","Valencia","Valladolid");
$col2=array('336','798466','90402','24214','142758','1658','8333','2253','14069','4877','77201','2714','171','32696','4','485','227','8157','4835','69246');
$col3=array("The Parmtree","Santiagounreal","TW","Bonz","Boom Shakalaka","Tangtastic","Declan McCarthy","Green Windmill","In Tommy We Trust","Ajay","Emperikal","Declan Quinn","Hillbilly Pete","Billy Gilmore","Demi","Yossi","Scroobius Mac","Chris_White","Old School","Pepin");
```

Comment: You mister are terrific :-)

Comment: Ignore, a simple regex find and replace works great in addition to that. Just ignore I asked.

Comment: Would like an explanation of what you did though...Rather than me just doing copy/paste....What do NF, NR, FS mean for example? A small explanation of what you did basically

Comment: man awk for the definitions of those variables. The script creates an array `col[]` indexed by the field number 1 -> 3 and for each line of input appends the value of each field number `i` on that line to the end of the string stored in `col[i]`. Once every line of the file has been read, it prints the array.